# Export text document in markdown format

Tags: node.js, github, markdown

I need to be able to save/export/convert a Rich Text Format or docx document into markdown (eg. "readme.md").

Next step needed is to convert those .md files into HTML and expose them on a website as static documentation.

I'll use NodeJs with [doctor-md](https://www.npmjs.com/package/doctor-md) to convert those files and [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to scrape the generated html and insert it into an existing template.

So far:

- I've seen [this script for Google Docs](http://lifehacker.com/this-script-converts-google-documents-to-markdown-for-e-511746113) but in my case non-dev people will copy and paste the markdown document directly on GitHub (using the editing tool) and that solution involves too many steps.
- I've found [this plugin for Microsoft Word](http://www.writage.com/) but it's for Windows only, they're working on Mac.
- I could directly save the Word document into HTML but non-dev users would then have to use git.

Any advice on how to easily produce those md files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [https://stackedit.io/](http://stackedit.io)? It converts html (or text) into markdown and doesn't require using Git. You can access it on their website or using the Chrome app. You can create titles and lists in the editor [here](http://stackedit.io/editor), and it will show you the corresponding text in markdown format. You can then save, publish, share, or download the file.